# Clicking on an element with the 5th highest price

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Please i am quite new to automation, been practising on an ecommerce site.
I am trying to sort in reversed order the items according to the price and then click on the item with the 5th highest price. i am stuck

This is my code:

```
List<WebElement> price = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='a-price-whole']"));

        // extract the prices from the price elements and store in a List
        List<Float> prices = new ArrayList<Float>();
        for (WebElement e : price)
        {
            prices.add(Float.parseFloat(e.getText()));
            
        }


        // sort the list
        
        Collections.sort(prices); 
        Collections.reverse(prices);
```

please assist

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this because I don't have the necessary libraries, (so there may be slight bugs) but I would get the top 5 web elements by price like this

```
List<WebElement> price = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='a-price-whole']"));
List<WebElement> top5 = price.stream().sorted(new Comparator<WebElement>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(WebElement e1, WebElement e2) {
            return Float.parseFloat(e1.getText()) > Float.parseFloat(e2.getText());
        }
    }).limit(5).toList();
```

Then you know the 5th element is the 5 most expensive. Plus you can access the web element instead of just the price. And click it with the click() selenium method.

You can also add any safeguards you need such as ensuring there are 5 elements, what if a price isn't listed, etc. But this should at least be enough to get you started

Comment: Thank you so much @M. Rogers, what if im trying to sort the whole list first, then pick the 5th highest. Do i remove the limit, then index the variable and click on it?

Comment: Yeah if you take out the limit it will do the whole list, and yeah that should work